# SQL Find rows that violate UNIQUE together index

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i want to put unique index on two (or more) columns in a table, but i get "duplicate keys found". How to select those rows which cause duplication?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `Group By` and `Having` for this:

```
SELECT col1,
       col2
FROM   table
GROUP  BY col1,
          col2
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Basically - group the values, then filter for instances where there is more than one.

Comment: +1 Now I don't have to finish writing my answer... You're too quick for me :)

Comment: @CW_Vaidotas Thank him by accepting his answer. This also spares others some time, when they don't have to study question+answer+comments, just to see that it's been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the following ways:

```
SELECT t1.rowid
FROM   this_table t1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT '1'
               FROM   this_table t2
               WHERE  t2.column_value1 = t1.column_value1
                      AND t2.column_value2 = t1.column_value2
                      AND t2.rowid > t1.rowid);

SELECT *
FROM   this_table_name a
WHERE  a.rowid > ANY (SELECT b.rowid
                      FROM   this_table_name b
                      WHERE  a.col1 = b.col1
                             AND a.col2 = b.col2);

SELECT my_column,
       Count(my_column)
FROM   this_table_name
GROUP  BY my_column
HAVING Count (my_column) > 1;
```